# Allowing users to choose an approval workflow to start in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

When using MOSS approval workflow on publishing pages I would like the users to be able to select a workflow to start rather than it just starting one? That is, when they click approve on a document I want a choice of approval workflows for them to select from i.e. Approval for the design team or Approval for the Corporate board etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with Content types then you can associate the workflows with the content types - the new button will allow the user to choose from one of the two content types, each with the appropriate workflow.

Otherwise, if you are not comforatable with content types and you are willing to copy items between lists using SharePoint designer, you could create 3 separate libraries, two of which host the workflows and the other to receive the approved documents. When your users begin authoring or uploading documents, direct the user to to two workflow lists upfront each with the appropriate workflow associated with it.  From there you could trigger the workflow and, upon approval a simple SharePoint Designer copy list item workflow could copy the approved item to the ultimate target list.

Comment: How would this work when editing an existing publishing page and sending for approval a second time i.e. not when creating a new file? thx

Comment: That's a good question.  The processes I map about above would really only work for new items.  I think that if you go the content type route you could still do something, possibly by allowing the user to pull down from a drop down list, choose option 1 or option 2 then, upon chnange, using a SharePoint designer workflow you could force change the content type by "SetFieldValue" to one of the two.  As I mentioned, you can attach a unique workflow to each content type.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how much code you want to write. Below forces you to write an event.

You could have a mandatory custom column on the document library called “workflow type”, make this a drop down list with the workflow types values. When you save the document the user will be forced to select a value.

Then write an post save event that looks at the “workflow type” column and attaches the correct workflow to the document.

easy :)